# "android:debuggable" make app die

Tags: android

everything was ok before today afternoon.
today, I update my android app. it is the start of problem.
google block uploading debuggable app to google market. 
so I remove 'android:debuggable="true";' in android manifest file.

ok~!! there is mysterious problem!!!

```
                                          run as                 export apk

android:debuggable="true"                  work                    work
android:debuggable="false"                 die                     die
android:debuggable="true" is removed       work                    die
```

what is happened in this app?
I have no idea...  TT
plz give me idea to solve this happening...

ps. I remove all logs and import logs in app.
    this app is base on google api 2.2, and tested many versions of android.

Answer (score 2):

`android:debuggable` is used for NDK programming.  Do you have NDK code?  If not, then you don't need `android:debuggable` at all.  Anyway, you can read more about that here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html
They explain how to turn this flag on/off from the command line.